# Grails Base64 decoding of Authorization header malformed on decode

Tags: java, grails, encoding, groovy, base64

I have a grails controller that base64 decodes the authorization header. I sent this from a PHP script using CURL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "testindia01@test.com:india123");
```

My grails console logging shows:

```
Authorization raw: Basic dGVzdGluZGlhMDFAdGVzdC5jb206aW5kaWExMjM=, isBase64: true
Authorization decoded: ´"q—ïÕ—•πë•Ñ¿≈—ïÕ–πçΩ¥È•πë•Ñƒ»Ã
```

In the above case I am using the Commons Base64 class, but using the Groovy built-in decodeBase64 yields the same result.

The Authorization raw coming in is correct. If I copy this and push it through PHP's ecode then it decodes properly.

```
echo base64_decode('dGVzdGluZGlhMDFAdGVzdC5jb206aW5kaWExMjM=');
```

If I copy the string directly into the controller, e.g.

```
def decode = new String(Base64.encodeBase64("dGVzdGluZGlhMDFAdGVzdC5jb206aW5kaWExMjM="))
```

Then this also correctly decodes.

I acquire the header via the request

```
def auth = request.getHeader("Authorization")
```

I test it is a valid base64 string with

```
Base64.isBase64(auth)
```

It's just the decode that fails. I have tried changing encodings on the decode.

def decoded = new String(auth.decodeBase64(), "UTF-8")

As well as other encodings like ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 but each time a different malformed string is returned.

I have also tried setting manually Accept-Encoding on the CURL request.

I am out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1):

This was because "Basic" has been included as part of the getHeader return value. If I strip this off it works. Base64.isBase64 only checks the characters are in the base64 alphabet, so "Basic " must have been.